# Russian flag instead of "ru" in panel

Tags: 18.04, icons, indicator

How can I change inscription "RU" in Ubuntu 18.04 panel to Russian flag?

I tried to change it through the dconf-editor, used `indicator-keyboard-Ru.svg` file coping into `/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22`. No flags.

Has anybody done it already?

Comment: Well it's certainly possible, cause I have an IPA keyboard with a blue letter eng `ŋ` symbol instead of the normal grey square with black text. I'm using 14.04 though.

Comment: Could you please specify your Ubuntu flavor and complete list of steps you did.